# Sabre BFM, getting just top few Results

Tags: sabre

Is there a way for me to retrieve the top few results via API? For example, the top 5 most preferred flights on the specified route and date? Or perhaps the top 10 most suitable and shortest duration flights on the specified route? I feel lost in the sea of documentation, if I could get a word, maybe an idea, or even a link from you, it could change everything. :)

Thank you in advance!